# IOS App rejected due to an unknown "_file"

Tags: appeal

A 5 year old app which was submitted every month successfully.

Recently got rejected saying.

“Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs: `ABLE.framework, _file`”

“Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.”

is `_file` is supposed to be rejected ? is `_file` is really a private API ?

Appeal is also rejected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a matter of a private company's policies, not law.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple: conform to the Apple Developer Guidelines or you can't use the App store.  We have no idea why `_file` was the cause of rejection, other than Apple makes the rules, and one of their rules is no use of "non-public APIs."

Apple is a private business and they administer their App store any way they want, within state and federal laws. You are bound by Apple's user agreement, a binding legal contract, which outlines reasons for App rejections, denial of appeals and canceling of your account, and venues for litigation or binding arbitration.

If you don't like the terms of the contract for the App store, you don't have to agree to it.

Comment: which means the previous submission are not really gone to the right hand to reject, only this time they caught it ?

Comment: You have to ask Apple; they made the decision. Your only recourse is to work with them, or take them to court.